# What feast is mentioned in John 5:1?

Tags: gospel-of-john, feasts

In [John 5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+5&version=NKJV), there is a story which takes place after "a feast of the Jews." What feast was this?

> After this there was a feast of the Jews, and Jesus went up to Jerusalem.

Comment: Because that's how long he had been sick.

Comment: @curiousdannii Ok I have done an edit ,asking now another question.But I do think It might be interesting that he had been sick for 38 years,maybe it has to do with some sin that leads to a certain sickness that will stay for that time and Jesus did lift the curse,I dunno.

Comment: I have edited your question further, to contain only the information relevant to your question, as I understand it.

Comment: This question looks as if it is not so much looking for a doctrinal position but a hermeneutic answer based on John:5:1.  It would probably be a better fit onour sister site, [BH.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions) where you could  not only find answers as to what the feast was but also why the 38 years were important to the narrative.

Comment: @Flimzy The edit is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Jean Christian Petitfils in his historical survey on Jesus' live states that this feast is more likely to be the Rosh ha-Shanah, the Jewish new year, which took place on 1st and 2nd of Tishiri (begining of automn 31). Unfortunatly he does not elaborate on that.

Cf. [Jean Christian Petitfils, *Jésus*, Fayard, Paris, 2011](http://www.fayard.fr/jesus-9782213654843), p 219.